# Efficiently solving a letter/number problem in Python

Tags: python, math

If `a = 15` and `152` is represented as `a2` while `215` is represented as `2a` then a number x has to be found such that

`8x = 8*x8`

I tried this naive Python code

```
>>> i = 0
>>> while(i<=100000000000000000):
...   if(int("8"+str(i))==8*int(str(i)+"8")):
...     break
...   i = i+1
... print i
```

but it is taking a huge amount of time to produce a correct result.

How to optimize the code?

Comment: Don't try to optimize the code you currently have. Use another algorithm instead.

Comment: Can you please suggest which algorithm has to be used?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A bit of math helps here: Let *x* be a natural number with *n* digits. Then 8x = 8 * 10^n + x, and x8 = 10*x + 8. So the equation to be solved is 8 * 10^n + x = 8 * (10*x + 8) = 80*x + 64, where *x* and *n* must be natural numbers. It immediately follows that x = (8 * 10^n - 64) / 79. Now we only have to check which of the numbers of the form 8 * 10^n - 64 is divisible by 79, which is very fast:

```
>>> n = 0
>>> while True:
...     y = 8 * 10**n - 64
...     if y % 79 == 0:
...         x = y / 79
...         break
...     n += 1
... 
>>> print x
101265822784
>>> print int("8"+str(x))==8*int(str(x)+"8")
True
```

Comment: Note that this is the dumbest possible algorithm. It could be much improved (e.g. by calculating the next *y* from the current *y* without calculation the exponential, calculating division and remainder at the same time, etc.), but you get the point.

Comment: And now that the algorithm is simplified, let me simplify the implementation ;) `next((8 * 10**n - 64) for n in count(0) if (8 * 10**n - 64) % 79 == 0)`.

Comment: That wouldn't be an improvement, as it would become less readable, and it is already very fast.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to get rid of str to int conversions.

First of all `8*int(str(i)+"8")` could be written as `8*(i*10+8)` and first part could be changed to `8*( int(log(i)/log(10))+1) + i`